# C - get chars from part of byte array

Tags: c, pointers, char, arrays

How can I get char array or char pointer from part of byte array? Let´s say I have variable-size string in byte array which begins at 18 bytes and ends 4 bytes from end of array. How can I get this?

Edit:
And what about dot? I should have dots in that byte array but when I copied by memcpy I get string without dots. How can I fix this?

Comment: I tried loop for and copy byte after byte. I forget about memcpy.

Comment: What do you mean by "dots" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To extract a part of an array, you can use `memcpy`.

```
#include <string.h>

char dst[4];

/* Here, we can assume `src+18` and `dst` don't overlap. */
memcpy(dst, src + 18, 4);
```

> **C11 (n1570), § 7.24.2.1 The `memcpy` function**
>   The `memcpy` function copies n characters from the object pointed to by `s2` into the
>   object pointed to by `s1`. If copying takes place between objects that overlap, the behavior
>   is undefined.

Comment: Yea, memcpy helps but I little extend my question. Look pls above.

Answer (score 2):

Well you can just use [memcpy](http://linux.die.net/man/3/memcpy) to copy any arbitrary range of bytes:

```
const int index1 = 18;    // start index in src
const int index2 = 252;   // end + 1 index in src

char src[256];            // source array
char dest[256];           // destination array

memcpy(dest, &src[index1], index2 - index1);
                          // copy bytes from src[index1] .. src[index2 - 1]
                          // inclusive to dest[0] .. dest[index2 - index1 - 1]
```

This will copy bytes from index 18 through 251 from `src` and store them in `dest`.

Comment: Which part are you having difficulty with ?

Comment: the `memcpy(dest,<problem-here>index2-index1</problem-here>, &src[index1])` part

Comment: I think you swap second and third parameters in memcpy but it´s not problem. I got once more problem which I described in edit in question please look at it.

Answer (score 1):

google the use of `memcpy`. it will satisfy your question

```
const char *buffer = "I AM A VERY VERY VERY VERY VERY VERY VERY VERY BIG STRING";
char buffer2[4];

memcpy(buffer2, (buffer+18), 4);
```

And fanny's your aunt.

Answer (score 0):

**memcpy(destination, source, count);**

- Destination = Storage Area (**!important** destination_SIZE >= count)
- Source = Array that holds the data to be copied (Default starting index = 0, But `source+n` can be skip `n` bytes(**You shouldn't be out of the source Array**))
- count = How many bytes will be copied.

A small warning: if the target is the same as the source, you must save all operands in the index.